how to configure the synopsys axi vip to arready/arvalid always asserted?
I want to let the master send transaction all the way, with no bubble in archannel.
So I add the constraint the conditon in seq:
class seq extends svt_axi_master_base_sequence;
    svt_axi_master_transaction trans;
    virtual task body();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i=i+1)begin
            `uvm_create_on(trans,m_sequencer)
            trans.randomize with{ trans.addr_valid_delay==0;
 trans.reference_event_for_addr_valid_delay == svt_axi_transaction::PREV_ADDR_VALID};
        end
    endtask    
endclass

and in axi_system_env:
this.master_cfg.zero_delay_enable==1;

but still bubbles in archannel like in red circle:

so is there any options I left??
